# Div under div css not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying following code for executing one alignment of boxes in right side with two adjacent box in row, please check below code why that main DIV class list_right css in not executing.

[Fiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/Amaryder/0moe8t7k/)

```css
<style>
.list_right {
    float:right;
    padding:40px 5px 0px 0px;
    width:37%;
    position:relative;
}
.part_1 {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    line-height: 1.7;
}
.logos {
    float: left;
    width:160px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:'Volkhov', arial;
    font-size: 19px;
    letter-spacing: 1.3px;
    line-height: 2.14;
    color: #6d6e71;
    border: 1px solid;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
    box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
    border-color: #41c7ee;
    behavior: url(/css/pie/PIE.htc);
}
.logos:hover {
    border-color: #6d6e71;
    background-color: #41c7ee !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
.site_1 {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/ndWHvar.png) !important;
    background-color: #f1f1f1 !important;
    background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
    background-position: 0px -5px !important;
    height:36px;
}
.site_2 {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/ndWHvar.png) !important;
    background-color: #f1f1f1 !important;
    background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
    background-position: 0px -5px !important;
    height:36px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="list_right">
<div class="part_1"> 
<a href="/" class="logos site_1">Sites</a>
</div>
<div class="part_1"> 
<a href="/" class="logos site_2">Sites</a>
</div>
<div class="d_hidden">

</div>
<div class="clear_both">

</div>
```

Comment: and where is this code? Please put it into a fiddle and post here

Comment: They seem pretty aligned to me

Comment: looks proper to me, and is executing. If I remove the list_right class it changes alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `<style>` tags in your css in your [original fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Amaryder/0moe8t7k/) which demonstrates the problem your were having.

Delete them, they shouldn't be there.

That's what's interfering with the list_right class.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/0moe8t7k/6/)**

Comment: Yeah it worked Thanks! BTW I am working on xamp and coding with Sublime text, is there any solution to check whether my codes are validating right or it might not got error while it live on web.

Comment: @AmarRyder - Something [like this](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2262)?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me (from your code) that you are not closing the list_right tag. Close it and it should work properly... try to indent your code, make it look more clean, so that in the future you will be able to see the problems yourself.